# Do data flow through SSIS server to the destination database server?

Tags: ssis

maybe silly but this is rather confusing to me. we have two server boxes one for SSIS integration service (IS) and the other dedicated to SQL Engine to host data warehouse. We have a job that calls SSIS package on the IS box to load data from another remote server onto the data warehouse server.

so, does the source data go through Integration Service Server first (in memory? ssis database?) and then land on target database server? or the Integration Service simply invokes the process for the db server to load the source data directly without going through the IS server. If former, putting IS and data warehouse on the same server should help the throughput?

A follow up question. what/how to monitor and troubleshoot the data flow then? for example, if I am loading a huge table and it appears to hang at times. The job is running with no error but I do not see insert activities on the destination server for a long time. where do I start looking. watch network activity on the IS server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A package executing on a dedicated server will require that all the data get shipped to that server and the pushed to the remote server.

[image: I made a picture]

This can be a good thing depending on how you SQL Server host is configured. SQL Server is going to use X amount of memory and it keeps it until the service is cycled. SSIS spins up, does its work and releases its resources. If you have allocated 8 GB of RAM for the OS and SQL Server gets the remaining N GB, then integration services only has 6ish GB of memory to work with. SSIS gets its transformative power through heavy use and abuse of memory. Drag a pair of sorts, merge join and some other memory fragmenting operators into your data flow, then you quickly winnow your memory down to nothing.

If you instead do all the transformation logic on the ETL box, you don't have to worry about impacting the SQL Server and the host OS until you start inserting into the target tables.

As long as the cost of serializing data from A to B and B to C is less than the cost of streaming it directly from A to C times two and some arbitrary fudge factor for the resulting memory contention, I don't see a problem with it. A more concrete example of where this wouldn't make sense - Fibre Channel HBAs from A to C but B is connected via 10-BaseT. For any data volume, the connectivity to and from B is going to be cause considerable drag on the processing.

### Data flow is stuck or appears non-responsive

First of all, I hope it's just the perception that it's stuck and you don't actually have the package open in VS and are "watching" it run. Running packages from within Visual Studio adds not-insignificant burden of the debugger. Shift-F5, run it from the command line with dtexec or schedule the job via SQL Agent/Windows Scheduler/Tidal/ActiveBatch/etc to get a "true" performance. Also, be sure you're using the 64 bit version of dtexec unless you need a driver that only exists in 32bit space.

At this point, I assume you have a package executing on the ETL Server through a non-burdensome mechanism. It's running but you have no idea what's happening just that it's not *done*. We can treat this as a black box and I would advise you to turn on the native SSIS Logging. Log to a SQL Server table (file works but then you have to do something with the file to get any insight). By default, I log OnPreExecute/OnPostExecute/OnWarning/OnError/OnInformation/OnTaskFailed in a package deployment model/pre-SQL Server 2012 world.

With those events logged, I can see when a task started and completed. I will see what configurations it's using and what might have been missed. What's broken (task Y failed), what can be improved (column X is not needed in the data flow), what might be a logical error (Lookup Z encountered duplicate keys in full cache mode), etc.

That won't tell me about what's happening between components in a data flow. For that, I need to log different events. In a 2005 environment, the only trick I'd have is a OnPipelineRowsSent event. With 2008+, we have some some new events (Pipeline*) available to us but I haven't done the research yet to see if they can provide the same information I can divine with OnPipelineRowsSent.

Because I'm lazy, I'd go with [OnPipelineRowsSent](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jamesn/archive/2008/02/11/60504.aspx) as I already have queries ready to parse that data and figure out where my slowdowns are. This event can be chatty so only turn as needed.

That's my blackbox route. You don't have to do that. You can see what your package is doing and you know your data.

Are there LOB data types coming across? SSIS does everything in memory. The pipeline figures out how much memory each row can theoretically take and makes calculations about how much data it can process at one time. Large OBject types (image/text/varX(max)) throw that to calculation to hell so under the covers, SSIS *might* be creating a tiny, or not so tiny, binary file to hold the LOB data and carries a pointer in the data flow task. All that disk activity kills your performance.

Do you have [asynchronous components](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jorg_klein/archive/2008/02/12/ssis-lookup-transformation-is-case-sensitive.aspx) in your data flow? That can slow your transformations way down.

Is your data source dog slow (like a web service)? Maybe you need to lower your buffer size.

Or, if you have a SQL Server source, you might just need to get some data into the pipeline as soon as possible so the [fast 10000](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/rob_farley/archive/2011/02/17/the-ssis-tuning-tip-that-everyone-misses.aspx) trick might help.

Maybe your OLE DB destination uses the 2005 default data access mode of Table or View. That's performing singleton inserts on your target system.

Along those same lines, do you have the `OLE DB Command` sitting in your data flow? That too fires off singleton operations.

How about those lookups - are you pulling back more columns than you need in a lookup? That's wasting memory. Do you need to pull all sales for all years or could you also filter those lookups by current year/rolling N months/etc?

How busy is the target system? Can SSIS get a table lock on the destination?

How much data are you loading to the target table relative to current size? How many non-clustered indexes are on that table. SQLCAT had a rule of thumb - 1 NCI and a 100% data increase; drop and recreate the index. More than 1 NCI and ~10 data load, drop and recreate. Never drop your clustered key. (these values are approximate and should be validated against your systems)

Finally, snag [sp_whoisactive](http://whoisactive.com) and install it strip the create/alter from the file and just run it "in-line" and see what's going on with your destination and source system if sql server, otherwise find an equivalent tool to monitor and make sure your connections are still alive, aren't blocked, etc.

Comment: it makes sense. in our case, we have stored procedures on the db server to do all the heavy transformation processing. I just wasn't clear the E part of ETL and how it flows. Thanks much for the clarification.

Comment: A follow up question. what/how to monitor and troubleshoot the data flow then? for example, if I am loading a huge table and it appears to hang at times. The job is running with no error but I do not see insert activities on the destination server for a long time. where do I start looking. watch network activity on the IS server? Thank you!

Comment: @JoyWalker Beefed up my answer. That help?

Comment: extremely informative. THANK YOU! Indeed, I use sp_whoisactive on the target server and many times I see no activity at all during the job run. Maybe I was just not looking at the right time. In most cases, the job do finish eventually. Thanks again.